# Concept for "this object looks like a 3D vector"

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I have a project which is using a few libraries where each one of the libraries define some sort of 3D vector, as an example I use [SFML's 3D vector](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Vector3.php) in some parts of the code, [reactphysics3d's](https://www.reactphysics3d.com/usermanual.html) `Vector3` on others, and yet another 3D vector from another library.

Now I need to code the cross product and the `std::ostream &operator <<` for each one of the vectors:

```
constexpr sf::Vector3f cross(const sf::Vector3f &a, const sf::Vector3f &b)
{
    return { a.y * b.z - a.z * b.y, a.z * b.x - a.x * b.z, a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x};
}

std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const sf::Vector3f &v)
{
    return o << '{' << v.x << ", " << v.y << ", " << v.z << '}';
}

// ... repeat for every 3D vector type
```

Which implies lots of code repetition, so I changed the approach:

```
template <typename vector3a_t, typename vector3b_t>
constexpr vector3a_t cross(const vector3a_t &a, const vector3b_t &b)
{
    return { a.y * b.z - a.z * b.y, a.z * b.x - a.x * b.z, a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x};
}
```

Now the `cross` function two types which are expected to have members `x`, `y` and `z` but obvuiously this isn't aplicable to `std::ostream &operator <<`:

```
template <typename vector3_t>
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const vector3_t &v)
{
    return o << '{' << v.x << ", " << v.y << ", " << v.z << '}';
}
```

because the template type `vector3_t` shadows everything, so I was wondering if it is possible to constrain the function to accept any type  that conforms the concept of "*should look like a 3D vector*":

```
template <typename vector_t>
concept vector3_c = requires(vector_t v) { // error: expected unqualified-id
    { std::is_scalar_v<decltype(v.x)> } -> true;
    { std::is_scalar_v<decltype(v.y)> } -> true;
    { std::is_scalar_v<decltype(v.z)> } -> true;
};

template <vector3_c A, vector3_c B>
constexpr decltype(A) cross(const A &a, const B &b)
{
    return { a.y * b.z - a.z * b.y, a.z * b.x - a.x * b.z, a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x};
}

template <vector3_c V>
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const V &v)
{
    return o << '{' << v.x << ", " << v.y << ", " << v.z << '}';
}
```

But this doesn't even compile. It's my first time attempting concepts and I don't know if what I'm trying to do is even possible.

Comment: For `operator<<` it isn't going to work, because overloaded operators should be in the same namespace as their parameters to be found by ADL.

Comment: *because the template type vector3_t shadows everything* What does this mean?

Comment: @super `vector3_t` is a template type that might match any type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
template <typename vector_t>
concept vector3_c = requires(vector_t v) { // error: expected unqualified-id
    { std::is_scalar_v<decltype(v.x)> } -> true;    
};
```

will only check the *validity* of the expression `std::is_scalar_v<decltype(v.x)>`. In addition, the *return-type-requirement* constrains the type not the value, so `-> true` is not correct, it should be `->std::same_as<bool>`.

You should use nested `requires` to *evaluate* the value of the expression, for example

```
template<typename vector_t>
concept vector3_c = requires(vector_t v) {
  requires std::is_scalar_v<decltype(v.x)> && 
           std::is_scalar_v<decltype(v.y)> &&
           std::is_scalar_v<decltype(v.z)>;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/KG9vP65zj)

If you just want to detect whether a struct has valid member variables, it is more intuitive to use a constraint expression of the form like `{v.x} -> scalar`

```
template<typename T>
concept scalar = std::is_scalar_v<T>;

template<typename vector_t>
concept vector3_c = requires(vector_t v) {
  { auto(v.x) } -> scalar;
  { auto(v.y) } -> scalar;
  { auto(v.z) } -> scalar;
};
```

where `auto(x)` is the language supported *decay-copy* in C++23, which we can use to remove the reference of the member variable access.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GKz8caq7P)

Answer (score 3):

If what you want is to check to see if a type has x,y,z members that are scalars, you can do this:

```
//Ensures that the user won't do something weird
template<typename T>
concept ref_to_scalar = std::is_reference_v<T> && std::is_scalar_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;

template<typename Vec>
concept vector_2d = requires(Vec v) {
  {v.x} -> ref_to_scalar;
  {v.y} -> ref_to_scalar;
};

//vec3d subsumes vec2d
template<typename Vec>
concept vector_3d = vector_2d<Vec> && requires(Vec v) {
  {v.z} -> ref_to_scalar;
};
```

Comment: And in C++23 there is no need to detect *reference*s, just `auto(v.x)`